# Comments shown over user information

Tags: bug

I haven't seen this before, but this is how [Cannot replace string from a file with another string shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49013418/1030675) is being displayed to me (Firefox 52.6 on Linux).

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this (as well as other similarly weird overlapping behaviour). I am also using Firefox 52.6 on Linux.

Comment: Looks fine using Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit) on a Windows machine

Comment: Related Meta-post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363935

Comment: Looks fine in 58.0.2 (64-bit) on Linux

Comment: Another (closed) duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363976