# Answer overlaps comments underneath

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4) the content shown in the first answer runs over the comments at the end of the post.  Can anyone confirm whether this is a bug or is it just my machine?

I'm running the latest version of Firefox ESR (long term support version) which is equivalent to Firefox 52.  I've done a Shift+Reload to clear any caches but the problem persists, so I'm just wondering whether any other Firefox users are also seeing it.

Here's a screenshot showing how I see the end of the first (highest-rated) answer:

> [image: Screenshot showing rendering issue]

Comment: no repro in chrome - mac sierra

Comment: Looks like its only in ESR version of firefox(52.6.0). Can repro in mac. Not reproducible in regular firefox stable

Comment: Also questions are affected, for example: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024678/docker-service-create-task-faild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024678/docker-service-create-task-faild)

Comment: Also the post doesn't need a comment to be affected, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49021146/8097737 [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI4v4.jpg)

Comment: Related Meta-post: [Comments shown over user information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363899)

Comment: No freehand red circle.  Where's the problem?

Comment: @kjhughes Maybe to much stuff to circle

Comment: @kjhughes the freehand red circle is there circling the whole thing, just *outside* the image.

Comment: Since the newest changes, my ancient firefox 26 shows the comments and questions/answers in parallel, but I'm an edge case.

Comment: I can also confirm for firefox-esr-52.6.0. Some questions with bounties are also affected, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885306/elastic-java-client-returns-different-result-from-http-api.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's [Firefox bug 1356820](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1356820) hitting you, which was fixed in version 54 but unfortunately not backported to the ESR version.

I've added the question/answer layout to the [CSS grid things we disable in old Firefoxes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306503/115866), so from the next build on, FF ESR will use the non-grid fallback layout (which doesn't line up things quite as nicely, but at least it works in browsers that don't support (or poorly support) the grid spec.

Comment: Nice, many thanks!  I'm amazed you found the specific bug at fault!  The build has deployed now and the problem has gone away.

Comment: Still not fixed on my end. As a Debian user, you may stick with the ESR version for a longer time. `52.9.0 (64-bit)` here.

Comment: @Roland Please note I don't work for Stack Overflow anymore, so if you want to make sure this gets seen by the powers that be, a comment on my answer isn't going to do the trick 

Comment: @balpha Yes, okay. It seem to be fixed. I'm not seeing it for some time now.