# Display error in posting

Tags: bug

This isn't a "question", but I don't see any other way to report this.

I'm noticing some display errors in how postings are displayed.  Tag names are displaying over the "add a comment" link, and the "share edit ..." links are almost on top of the "question eligible" statement.  The following is a segment of the page of a question I asked today:

[image]

I thought it was just a temporary "glitch", but when I redisplayed the page, it came up the same way.

**Update**:

It's now even worse, and it's now breaking the page functionality.  I can't reach the "edit" link to edit my posting:

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox. This is now more critical. I can't even reach the link for "edit" to modify my posts.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr: I suppose being more specific would help; which version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Well, it's 52.5.3 (32-bit) , but my posting is now displaying perfectly fine today. Either something was fixed, or some sort of race condition or threshold was passed.