# Is Stack Overflow CSS broken or is it my web browser fault?

Tags: bug, design, comments

On some questions the comment section is rendered at too high position and it overlaps with the
bottom of the question, for example:

[image]

and

[image]

The funny thing is that this happens only on some questions, others are looking
fine. So far I haven't seen this behaviour on answers.

I use Gentoo Linux and run Firefox ESR 52.6.0 (64-bit), I've made an update last week.
I'm very active in Stack Overflow, so if it was the update, I should have seen this behaviour earlier, but
it started happening today.

I started Google Chrome (64.0.3282.186) and checked if the same questions yields the same
results. But Google Chrome renders the comment section at the correct place.

Is this an Firefox issue or a CSS from Stack Overflow issue?

Comment: @DavyM so I'm not the only one, but I must suck at searching, because I didn't find any of these questions :(

Comment: On the list of newest meta questions, that first dupe was 3 below this one you've just asked, and it was linked to the other one already as a duplicate. But we all have off days, you'll find the next dupe.

Comment: @DavyM They wasn't there when I wrote the question, all I got was mostly questions whether we should answer design questions or not.

Comment: We've got a third one :) [Is Stack Overflow CSS broken or is it my web browser fault?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363982/is-stack-overflow-css-broken-or-is-it-my-web-browser-fault?noredirect=1&lq=1). None of them found the duplicates either, so don't feel bad ;D

Comment: @DavyM you linked this question ;)

Comment: I could have sworn I had a different question highlighted how embarrassing...

Comment: Hahaha this is the one I meant to link. [Comments shown over user information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363899/comments-shown-over-user-information?noredirect=1&lq=1). Anyways, I think I got them all this time.

Comment: @DavyM don't worry, everyone makes mistakes :)

Comment: The problem seems to be the same, so this question seems to me a dupe. However, I can't see the same problem on my browser.

Comment: @Laurel A bit slow ;-) (Already posted - see [the second comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363982/is-stack-overflow-css-broken-or-is-it-my-web-browser-fault?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment561392_363982).)